# Save a ggplot allowing panning and zooming

Tags: r, ggplot2, zooming, pan, ggsave

I'm creating a series of small line graphs relevant to different regions which I then save as grobs and plot onto a map of Europe. I can save this as a png file and can then zoom in to parts on the saved image just with standard windows photo zoom. However this is quite slow, the zoomed image takes quite a while to load. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this and tried with svgPanZoom but I couldn't get the grobbed plots the right scale so that they were visible instead you could juts see the axes not the graph itself and I also couldn't work out how to save the plot so that panning and zooming was still possible.

Does anyone known a better way to do this?
My code is below but the dataset is too big to post an example.

```
  ###species_preds is a list of model prediction dataframes for different 100km squares in Europe 
  ##so dt is a dataframe with a column for julian day, one for prediction and one each for the upper and lower confidence intervals
 
  ##list_100km_sp is a dataframe of the  x and y centroid locations of all the 100km squares we have prediction 
  data for
 
  ##Europe is a base map, just a filled polygon of Europe 

  list_plots<-list()
  
  
  for (g in 1:length(species_preds)){
    dt<-species_preds[[g]]
    #qualify what's plotted by sample size?
    p<-ggplot(data=dt)+
      geom_line(aes(x=date, y=round(pred,3), group=1),linetype="solid", size=0.05)+
      geom_line(aes(x=date, y=round(u.pred,3), group=1),linetype="dashed", size=0.05)+
      geom_line(aes(x=date, y=round(l.pred,3), group=1),linetype="dashed", size=0.05)+
      xlab("Julian_date")+ylab("Prob of occurrence")+
      theme(legend.position = "none",panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            plot.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size=0.05),
            axis.ticks=element_line(size=0.05),
            text = element_text(size=1), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
    
    list_plots[[g]]<-ggplotGrob(p)
  }
  
  ##plot all on a map
   plot <- Europe + annotation_custom(grob=list_plots[[1]], xmin=list_100km_sp$centroid_x_rounded[1], xmax=list_100km_sp$centroid_x_rounded[1]+130000, ymin=list_100km_sp$centroid_y_rounded[1], ymax=list_100km_sp$centroid_y_rounded[1]+130000)
  for (i in 2:length(list_plots)){
    plot <- plot + annotation_custom(grob=list_plots[[i]], xmin=list_100km_sp$centroid_x_rounded[i], xmax=list_100km_sp$centroid_x_rounded[i]+130000, ymin=list_100km_sp$centroid_y_rounded[i], ymax=list_100km_sp$centroid_y_rounded[i]+130000)
  }
  
  
  ggsave(plot, file="species.png"), dpi=600, height = 90, width =80, units="cm", pointsize=6)
```

[full map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eitx.png)
[image: zoomed map section]

Comment: What is the total file size of the PNG created (the large one)?

Comment: It's 3.8Mb for the whole map

Comment: Try Sirv Zoom - it generates deep zoom for images up to 32MB. https://sirv.com/help/articles/image-zoom/